# JS batch progress bar: possible to force refresh more frequently than every 1500 ms?

Tags: ajax

After initiating a js-based batch with `batch_set()`, and the redirect to batch do URL, the JS refresh interval is every 1500 ms by default. So status message and progress bar are only updated every 1 1/2 seconds. For a specific application I need the refresh to happen more rapidly, let's say, every 500 ms. I couldn't find anything in `batch_set()` to set the refresh interval.

I believe that D8 core decides in file `core/misc/ajax.es6.js` that the default refresh interval ought to be 1500 ms, if nothing else specified:

```
if (this.progress.url) {
  progressBar.startMonitoring(
    this.progress.url,
    this.progress.interval || 1500,
  );
```

I could be wrong though and this code being only related to Ajax throbbers and such. The form Ajax API seems to have a way to pass `#interval` but I couldn't find anything for the batch API.

Be that as it may, my question is, how do I set my own custom refresh interval in a `batch_set()`, or if not there, is there another clean way to override the 1500 ms?

Thanks!

Comment: For testing purposes, what happends when u change that  ajax.es6.js `1500` to something else? Does it do what u need?

Comment: @NoSssweat It would not change anything, since ajax.es6.js isn't loaded in any page.

Comment: Put simply, you need to monkey patch whatever method has that magic number in it, and replace it either with a different magic number to suit your needs, or make it configurable. Should be easy to do, but whether it proves to be maintainable depends on how much code you have to replace to get to that single line. I’d also submit a feature request to fix it in core, we shouldn’t have magic numbers in this day and age

Comment: Are you pretty sure about the refresh every 1500ms? - Just did a little digging in the code and found that the batch progress bar JavaScript has a hard-coded delay of 10ms. It is set after each successful response from the batch API callback URL (compare `core/misc/batch.es6.js`, line 39: `progressBar.startMonitoring('${batch.uri}&op=do', 10);`, and `core/misc/progress.es6.js`, lines 99ff., `Drupal.ProgressBar.startMonitoring()`/`Drupal.ProgressBar.sendPing()`). That leaves me to suppose, that the callback of your batch just needs about a second or so to complete?

Comment: Yes, @MarioSteinitz is correct: 1500 is the default value used from AJAX, but the batch API uses 10.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz you nailed it. I was pulling my hair out why so few refreshes, and I had a sub sub loop iterate too many times for testing, grrr. I was mislead by old information at [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53512/theme-the-progress-bar-when-in-batch-api-with-ajax) and my batch call randomly took about 1500ms give or take. The core timeout interval in the sendPing() "loop" is indeed 10 ms PLUS whatever time your batch callback needs.

Comment: @Clive the hardcoded value is indeed a callback every 10 ms which is rather high frequency to hammer your own site with, if the batch PHP doesn't do much hehe... but in principle I agree with you, it should be configurable. The net effect of a higher value would be to artificially slow the batch down, should that be desired. But perhaps even such delays should be better coded in the batch PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Turns out none of us (neither I or nor the commenters) were completely "right", nor completely "wrong".** There **IS** an arbitrary limit hardcoded in D8's core, for JS batch progress bar refreshes, but it's not 1500 ms as I thought -- it's 1000 ms.

And it's harcoded in a different place than any of us thought.

As @MarioSteinitz stated, yes, the batch API inserts only a very short pause between two Ajax requests -- 10 ms. (The Ajax API is different with its 1500 ms default pause and I mixed up the two.)

**However, try as I might, I couldn't get the progress bar to refresh more often than once every approximately 1.1 or 1.2 seconds.** No matter how fast I finished my simulated batch work (by reducing my `usleep()` in the batch code), the relevant DOM objects, such as `progress__bar`, were never refreshing more frequently than just over once a second.

You can easily see their "throbbing" in Inspector's DOM view and count *onethousand-one, onethousand-two* as they pulse away... even when my batch function did absolutely nothing, the fastest I could get these DOMs to flash was just over once a second.

**So what gives?**

**Well the batch API is just weiiiiirrrrrd...** instead of giving the programmer the say in how much work ONE Ajax request is supposed to do, the function `_batch_process()` in core file `/core/includes/batch.inc` has a loop **harcoded** that calls the batch function again and again until at least 1000 ms have passed (or the batch is finished):

```
// If we are in progressive mode, break processing after 1 second.
if ($batch['progressive'] && Timer::read('batch_processing') > 1000) {
  // Record elapsed wall clock time.
  $current_set['elapsed'] = round((microtime(TRUE) - $current_set['start']) * 1000, 2);
  break;
}
```

**Weird because a batch is ALREADY supposed to be a large process chopped into small bite-sized chunks.** So the entire batch already **IS** a loop, but there's, in fact, a **secondary inner loop**, whose break conditions are outside of the coder's control!

You think this kind of policing of the programmer's wishes is not weird, arbitrary and unnecessary? Well consider that that the batch API (after what feels like decades), still doesn't allow progressive batches (i.e. batches that are all processed in one swoop, for example from the shell) -- see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/638712.

**But I digress.**

**So for sh*ts and giggles I changed the > 1000 to > 100 in the above core code and what do you know, the progress DOMs refreshed like crazy!**

Of course I can empathize with the idea that no batch should hammer its host server with heavy requests every 10 ms, for obvious reasons. So the developers decided to loop and re-loop the batch function until at least 1000 ms have passed, before the next Ajax call is triggered.

**Well-intentioned? Yes! Arbitrary and inflexible? Absolutely.** As the programmer of a batch, I believe it should be **MY** choice how much exactly I want to do in one Ajax call. Any Drupal code has the potential to crash or deadlock the server, or overwhelm the browser. Why police this particular part?

**Drupal maintainers:** Why not default to 1000 ms if that is a trusty value for most applications or unaware coders, but for batches that require a more dense flow of output, let's say, once every 100 ms, give us the power to do that!

**So how to get rid of the pesky > 1000 condition - without hacking the Drupal core of course!?**

```
if ($batch['progressive'] && Timer::read('batch_processing') > 1000) {
```

**If this were D7, we'd just manipulate the global $timers array:** Just before our batch function exits, set its start value back to the stone age (01/01/1970), and the calling `_batch_process()` will always "think" at least one second has passed, and give control back to Ajax immediately.

Just that this isn't your grandma's Drupal; we are now all fancy object-oriented and stuff.

Looking at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Timer.php/8.2.x we notice that we can't just poke whatever we want into the `Timer::$timers` array any more. It is declared `protected`, i.e. no outsider, such as my batch function, is allowed to mess with its internal values.

**So we're back to square one... or are we?**

Well thankfully this is PHP and not a "real" programming language! *(ducks)*

Meaning, there's always a loophole to bypass any new-fangled OOP restrictions that those eggheads at Software Engineering University demanded. *To hell with them!*

After some googling, I wrote the following function. And by "wrote" I mean I all but stole it from people who know much more about PHP than I do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448551/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-private-protected-static-property-using-reflection-cla

```
  /**
   * Revert Timer::$timers['batch_processing'] back to the stone age
   * to trick batch.inc / _batch_process() into thinking at least 1 second has passed
   */
  protected static function revertTime() {

    $obj         = new Timer();
    $refObject   = new ReflectionObject($obj);
    $refProperty = $refObject->getProperty('timers');
    $refProperty->setAccessible(true);
    $myTimers = $refProperty->getValue();
    $myTimers['batch_processing']['start'] = 0;
    $refProperty->setValue(null, $myTimers);

  }
```

I now call `revertTime()` at the very end of all my "batch on crack" functions, *juuuuust* before they exit. It sets the start time of `_process_batch()`'s `Timer::$timers['batch_processing']['start']` to 0.

**And 0 is always more than one second ago.**

The effect is that `_batch_process()` never loops; the Ajax call terminates after exactly one call to my batch function.

10 ms later, the batch API initiates another Ajax call to my batch function, resulting potentially in a rat-tat-tat machine-gunning refresh cycle for my progress bar.

**NOTE OF CAUTION:** When I first ran this, with all checks and balances disabled, it overwhelmed Chrome with its rapid-fire Ajax calls every 10 ms. Today was a hot day (I live in the southern hemisphere) and my Mac slowed down to a crawl under the load of the Ajax calls... the built-in overheat protection kicked in!

**When you use this hack, it is your responsibility to make your batch functions either do a LOT of slow stuff in one iteration, or waste sufficient time with `usleep()`. Otherwise the batch staccato may overwhelm your visitor's browser or your server.**

Thanks again to all the contributors here and elsewhere who finally led me to a semi-clean (non-core hack) solution! ❤️